# Conjecture that there are finitely many integer powers $a^x$ and $b^y$ such that $b^y - a^x = n$: who first came up with it?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I came up with an interesting mathematical conjecture: for every natural number $n$ there is only a **finite** number of integer powers $a^x$ and $b^y$ such that $b^y - a^x = n$.

I would like to find out what it is called and who first came up with it.

Comment: This is known as Pillai's conjecture, a generalisation of Catalan's conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)

Comment: @ThomasBloom Catalan's conjecture is not covered by Pillai's conjecture, since the latter only says that there are finitely many solutions (and not just the obvious ones).

Comment: Depends a bit on what you call an "integer power". $17=18^1-1^1=19^1-2^1=\dotsb=5^2-8^1=6^2-19^1=\dotsb$.